# WPF: Custom Datagrid with Checboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I want to create a DataGrid in our application which looks like this:

```
|Name|Email      |OC |Path|01.01.17|05.08.17|... (more dates and checkboxes)
|Foo |foo@bar.com|...|... |[x]     |        |...
|Bar |bar@bar.com|...|... |[ ]     |[x]     |...
|Foo |foo@bar.com|...|... |        |[ ]     |...
```

As you can see the column count has to be dynamic and the checkbox column can contain either a checkbox or nothing.
My approach was to use a converter to build my DataTable.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var techWithDates = (TechFvo[])value;
    var dataTable = new DataTable();

    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Email"));
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OC"));
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Path"));

    if (techWithDates == null)
        return dataTable.DefaultView;

    var days = GetFormattedDays(techWithDates);
    foreach (var day in days)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(day, typeof(bool)));

    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataTable.NewRow());

    foreach (var tech in techWithDates)
    {
        if (tech.GetTerminListe().Count == 0)
            continue;

        var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        dataRow[0] = tech.Name;
        dataRow[1] = tech.EMail;
        dataRow[2] = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tech.Path) ? "No" : "Yes";
        dataRow[3] = tech.Path;
        AddTechCols(dataRow, tech, days);
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }

    return dataTable.DefaultView;
}

private void AddTechCols(DataRow row, TechFvo techs, List<string> aDays)
{
    var dates = techs.GetTerminListe();
    var datesAsStrList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var date in dates)
    {
        var thisStr = DateToString(date.Day);
        if (!datesAsStrList.Contains(thisStr))
            datesAsStrList.Add(thisStr);
    }

    foreach (var aDay in aDays)
    {
        if (datesAsStrList.Contains(aDay))
            row[aDay] = true;
        else
            row[aDay] = DBNull.Value;
    }
}
```

This works but there are checkboxes in every checkbox column in every row.
How do I hide a checkbox in a column when I build the row?

I tried

```
row[aDay] = false;
row[aDay] = null;
row[aDay] = DbNull.Value();
```

but nothing worked...
Thanks!

Comment: can you please give any feedback to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can intercept the moment when DatagridCheckBoxColumns is created and change CheckBoxes settings.

add event handler `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn">
</DataGrid>
```

```
// fixing checkboxes in DataGrid DataGridCheckBoxColumns
private void DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    var column = e.Column as DataGridCheckBoxColumn;
    if (column == null)
        return;

    var dg = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dg == null)
        return;

    column.ElementStyle = (Style)dg.FindResource("DateChk");
    column.EditingElementStyle = (Style)dg.FindResource("DateChk");
}
```

"DateChk" is CheckBox style, declared in Resources, which makes CheckBox hidden and disabled when value is `null` (or `DBNull.Value` in DataTable)

```
<Style x:Key="DateChk" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```