# Colorize Autogenerated Columns from DataTable in wpf DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, datagrid

I am currently creating a DataTable with (optional) column names which I load into a DataGrid

```
List<string[]> ImportTable;
public void GeneratePreview()
{
    // Build datatable
    DataTable csvPreview = new DataTable();
    // generate Columns (with headers if selected)
    for (int i = 0; i < ImportTable[0].Length; i++)
    {
        csvPreview.Columns.Add();
        if ((bool)HasHeaders_Checkbox.IsChecked)
        {
            // specify table headers   
            csvPreview.Columns[i].ColumnName = ImportTable[0][i];
        }
    }
    /* Add records excluded here as not beneficiary for the question */
    // build display output
    this.ImportPreview.ItemsSource = csvPreview.AsDataView();
}
```

This is for previewing csv data, selecting the correct splitter, encoding and specifying column names.

The Preview so far looks fine. The headers are there and the data is there.
[image]

There might be a lot of e-waste-columns which are not beneficiary to my project or the Columns have inconsistent names, dependend which bank statement I'm importing.
Hence I want to mark the Columns which are imported.
I tried the following:

```
// ImportPreview is my Datagrid in WPF xaml
this.ImportPreview.Columns[index].CellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
this.ImportPreview.Columns[index].CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue)));
```

This works when I have added columns manually. The Autogenerated Columns are not beeing considered:

```
// Index was 1 and the DataGrid actually has 8 Columns

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'
```

[image]

please help colorizing autogeneraded Columns.

Answer (score 0):

The Columns Get mapped correctly when adding Columns to the DataTable AND to the DataGrid:

```
// generate Columns (with headers if selected)
for (int i = 0; i < ImportTable[0].Length; i++)
{
    csvPreview.Columns.Add();
    DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();
    string columnName;
    if ((bool)HasHeaders_Checkbox.IsChecked)
    {
        // specify Column Name
        columnName = ImportTable[0][i];
    }
    else
    {
        // generate generic names
        columnName = "Column " + i;
    }
    csvPreview.Columns[i].ColumnName = columnName;
    col.Binding = new Binding(columnName);
    col.Header = columnName;
    this.ImportPreview.Columns.Add(col);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Note: The generation of generic names is very important to map the columns. If no generic names are specified, the mapping is incorrect and the result will look something like this:
[image]

Note 2:
`AutoGenerateColumns="False"` should be set in xaml to the Data grid

Comment: "AutoGenerateColumns="False" should be set in xaml to the DataGrid" - why is that? it is simple to add CellStyle to generated columns, like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45774455/1506454

Comment: it will otherwise also autogenerate columns from the DataTable leading to duplicated Columns like `Column1; Column2; column3; Column1; Column2; Column3; `

Comment: if you apply both solutions at the same time, then yes, you will have two copies of required columns. my point is that autogenerated columns can be customized too. and it is MVVM compliant

Comment: I dont know how to do it. But feel free to post an Answer.

Comment: I posted a link to an answer. same principle here